# PHP Regex Match Newlines and Characters Except

Tags: regex

I want to create a regex in php that matches all characters excluding ; but including all newlines. I can match all characters except ; easily with the regex:

```
[^;]
```

And I can match any character including newlines with the regex:

```
.*/s
```

But I'm not sure how to combine the two to get the result I desire. I would prefer not having to create a large regex that includes all numbers, symbols, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
[^;]+
```

This will match newlines (since they are not `;`), you just have to tell it to match more than just one character.

**Demo:** [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/oF6dJ1)

---

**Implementation:**

```
$string = 'foo
bar
abc;123
test
';

preg_match_all('/[^;]+/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);

// array(1) {
//   [0]=>
//   array(2) {
//     [0]=>
//     string(13) "foo
// bar
// abc"
//     [1]=>
//     string(11) "123
// test
// "
//   }
// }
```

---

**Alternative:**

Is there a chance you just want to use [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), here are examples using the same `$string` as above:

```
$string = str_replace(';', '', $string);
var_dump($string);

// string(24) "foo
// bar
// abc123
// test
// "
```

OR

```
$parts = explode(';', $string);
var_dump($parts);

// array(2) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(13) "foo
// bar
// abc"
//   [1]=>
//   string(11) "123
// test
// "
// }
```

Comment: If this doesn't do what you want, please elaborate on your question of an expected input/match.